# Spring Boot Live Reloading not working on Mac

Tags: intellij-idea, spring-boot, livereload

So, I'm having issues with a Spring Boot Gradle project and LiveReloading on a Mac. It works fine for all of our Windows developers. However, our UI/UX person has a Mac and it only reloads the HTML and JS. All the static content (HTML and CSS) resides under /srv/main/resources/resources/views and ./styles, respectively.

Spring Boot: 1.3.3.RELEASE
IntelliJ: Version: 2016.2 Build: 162.1121.32

I've followed the directions in the Spring Boot docs and also the instructions on several blogs:

- https://patrickgrimard.io/2016/01/18/spring-boot-devtools-first-look/
- http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/using-boot-devtools.html

I've edited the IntelliJ registry and enabled the addResource property for the bootRun gradle task. Nothing fully enables live reload for the Mac. Neither automatic nor manual making propagates the change(s).

Any ideas? JVM? Something Mac specific I'm missing?

Thanks

Comment: Apparently this is only happening for css files. I tried moving the css file to the views folder, which was propagating changes for html files, and it still failed. So it's not a path issue but a file extension issue.

Comment: Even stranger it only picks up the changes to main.css. No other css file. Not even the css files in the same directory.